# Is there any way to know the time of the request reaching Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have an internal component passing request to Nginx. Logs on my internal component show 96500 ms as response times. But the same request shows 0.010 ms in Nginx.  I did check the network connection between the components but all look ok. Is there any way to know the time request reached Nginx? I guess the request reached time might be different. Can someone put some light into this? Let me know if anyone needs any config for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your client and server are synced using a NTP server. You can then add a request time to the url before making the request

```
http://example.com/url/?start_time=xxxxxx
```

Then on server logs you can log time taken using `$request_time` and also add the time to response using add headers

```
add_header X-Request-Time $time_iso8601;
```

On the client side you can then log when you get the response. So you will almost have all the time points with you.

- `start_time` on client when you sent the request
- `X-Request-Time` in response header for when request reached nginx
- `$request_time` in nginx log telling you when it started responding to the request
- `end_time` on client when you received the response